# Set default header value for sample requests in generated documentation

Tags: php, api-doc

I'm trying to set up sample requests for my api docs. It works fine but i need manyally set header values for every request

[image: form example]
Is there a way to define default value for header that will be sent with every sample request?

I've tried to set default value for headers like:

```
/**
 * @apiHeader {String} Authorization=someToken
 * @apiHeader {String} Content-Type=application/json
 */
```

Also I was thinking about including custom js in generated html that will fill these fields (I'm not sure if it's possible) but I hope there is a simplier solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The owner of the apidoc/apidoc writes [here](https://github.com/apidoc/apidoc/issues/411#issuecomment-180287345):

> You can set default values. But the send sample request module did not
>   use the default value at the moment (you can modify the template for
>   this).

Comment: Did my answer help solve the problem, @Andriy Lozynskiy?